# R Index error while trying to append multiple dataframes into one

Tags: r, indexing, vectorization

So I have a massive dataframe and I'm trying to combine scores I calculated from multiple dataframes (about 17 dataframes) to this one dataframe and I need to do this process 12 different times. This is an example dataframe that I have

```
df=structure(list(ï..id = structure(c(2L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 
8L), .Label = c("B12", "B7", "C2", "C9", "D3", "E2", "E6", "R4"
), class = "factor"), age = c(42L, 45L, 83L, 59L, 49L, 46L, 52L, 
23L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

So I need to calculate network metrics using the `igraph` package. Here are 2 matrices I have with different people in them

```
net_mat1=structure(c("B7", "E6", "D3", "C9"), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("ï..target", "partner")))

net_mat2=structure(c("C2", "B12", "E2", "R4"), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("ï..target", "partner")))
```

Here is what I'm calculating

```
library(igraph)
g1=graph_from_edgelist(net_mat1)
g2=graph_from_edgelist(net_mat2)

degree_cent_close_1=centr_degree(g1, mode = "all")
degree.cent_close_1 #create object that contains metrics

degree.cent_close2=centr_degree(g2, mode = "all")
degree.cent_close2 #create another object that contains metrics
```

I then create dataframes that contain the metrics I calculated

```
cent_score_df1=data.frame(degree_cent_close_1$res, V(g1)$name)
cent_score_df1

cent_score_df2=data.frame(degree.cent_close2$res, V(g2)$name)
cent_score_df2
```

I then try to match and index the the values of these metrics back into the `df` dataframe doing this

```
df$centrality_scores <- cent_score_df1[ match(df[['id']], cent_score_df1[['V.g1..name']] ) , 'degree_cent_close_1.res']
df$centrality_scores



df$centrality_scores <- cent_score_df2[ match(df[['id']], cent_score_df2[['V.g2..name']] ) , 'degree.cent_close2.res']
df$centrality_scores
```

However, it seems each time I try to merge my data with the original dataframe it can only attach half the data. I can never attach both dataframes. Does anyone have a better method that works for re-attaching data? If there are faster and cleaner ways of doing this I would greatly appreciate the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this line of code, is you are not selecting the rows in the original data.frame to update, instead you are just updating the first 4 rows.

```
df$centrality_scores <- cent_score_df1[ match(df[['id']], cent_score_df1[['V.g1..name']] ) , 'degree_cent_close_1.res']
```

What you intended was to do this:

```
df$centrality_scores<-NA
df$centrality_scores[na.omit(match(df$id, cent_score_df1$id))]<- cent_score_df1$V.g1..name
```

Another way to solve this is standardize the column names of your metric data frames and then use the `merge` function to add the results back to your original data frame.

```
names(cent_score_df1)<-c("centrality_scores", "id")
names(cent_score_df2)<-c("centrality_scores", "id")
cent_score<-rbind(cent_score_df1, cent_score_df2)
merge(df, cent_score, by.x="id", by.y="id")
```